# Distinct Records with joins and order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, join, sql-order-by

I have a simple relationship between `User` and `Donations` in that a user has many donations, and a donation belongs to a user. **What I'd like to do is get a list of users, ordered by the most recent donations.**

Here's what I'm trying:

First I want to get the total number of uniq users, which is working as expected:

```
> User.joins(:donations).order('donations.created_at').uniq.count
   (3.2ms)  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "users"."id") FROM "users" INNER JOIN "donations" ON "donations"."user_id" = "users"."id"
 => 384
```

Next, when I remove the `count` method, I get an error that "ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list":

```
> User.joins(:donations).order('donations.created_at').uniq
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "donations" ON "donations"."user_id" = "users"."id" ORDER BY donations.created_at
PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...ON "donations"."user_id" = "users"."id"  ORDER BY donations....
```

Then I tried fixing the Postgres error by explicitly setting the SELECT clause which at first glance appears to work:

```
 > User.select('DISTINCT "users".id, "users".*, "donations".created_at').joins(:donations).order('donations.created_at')
  User Load (17.6ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "users".id, "users".*, "donations".created_at FROM "users" INNER JOIN "donations" ON "donations"."user_id" = "users"."id" ORDER BY donations.created_at
```

However, the number of records returned does not take into account the DISTINCT statement and returns 692 records:

```
> _.size
 => 692
```

**How do I get the expected number of results (384) while also sorting by the donation's created_at timestamp?**

Comment: I suppose when you say `DISTINCT "users".id, "users".*, "donations".created_at` server interprets that as: one result per each element that is unique in all its fields

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
User.select('users.*,MAX(donations.created_at) as most_recent_donation').
  joins(:donations).order('most_recent_donation desc').group('users.id')
```

I suppose an user has many donations, this would select the most recent created donation and would select distinct users filtering by their id.

I have not tested this though.

Comment: Using `group('users.id')` I get a postgres error "column "donations.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: Your updated answer worked for me, thanks! The only change I made was to use `order('most_recent_donation DESC')` because I am using this with [Kaminari pagination](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari), and wanted the most recent donors first.

Comment: ah I understand, nice.