# How to make Rails/ActiveRecord return unique objects using join table's boolean column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Rails 4 app using ActiveRecord and Postgresql with two tables: `stores` and `open_hours`. a `store` has many `open_hours`:

stores:

```
       Column       | 
--------------------+
 id                 | 
 name               |
```

open_hours:

```
    Column       |
-----------------+
 id              |
 open_time       |
 close_time      |
 store_id        |
```

The `open_time` and `close_time` columns represent the number of seconds since midnight of Sunday (i.e. beginning of the week).

I would like to get list of `store` objects ordered by whether the store is open or not, so stores that are open will be ranked ahead of the stores that are closed. This is my query in Rails:

```
Store.joins(:open_hours).order("#{current_time} > open_time AND #{current_time} < close_time desc")
```

Notes that `current_time` is in number of seconds since midnight on the previous Sunday.

This gives me a list of stores with the currently open stores ranked ahead of the closed ones. However, I'm getting a lot of duplicates in the result.

I tried using the distinct, uniq and group methods, but none of them work:

```
Store.joins(:open_hours).group("stores.id").group("open_hours.open_time").group("open_hours.close_time").order("#{current_time} > open_time AND #{current_time} < close_time desc")
```

I've read a lot of the questions/answers already on Stackoverflow but most of them don't address the `order` method. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970153/distinct-records-with-joins-and-order) seems to be the most relevant one but the `MAX` aggregate function does not work on booleans.

Would appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve the issue:

In Rails:

```
is_open = "bool_or(#{current_time} > open_time AND #{current_time} < close_time)"

Store.select("stores.*, CASE WHEN #{is_open} THEN 1 WHEN #{is_open} IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 3 END AS open").group("stores.id").joins("LEFT JOIN open_hours ON open_hours.store_id = stores.id").uniq.order("open asc")
```

Explanation:

- The `is_open` variable is just there to shorten the `select` statement.
- The `bool_or` aggregate function is needed here to group the `open_hours` records. Otherwise there likely will be two results for each store (one open and one closed), which is why using the `uniq` method alone doesn't eliminate the duplicate issues
- `LEFT JOIN` is used instead of `INNER JOIN` so we can include the stores that don't have any `open_hours` objects
- The store can be **open** (i.e. true), **closed** (i.e. false) or **not determined** (i.e. nil), so the `CASE WHEN` statement is needed here: if a store is open, then it's **1**, **2** if not determined and **3** if closed
- Ordering the results `ASC` will show **open** stores first, then the **not determined** ones, then the **closed** stores.

This solution works but doesn't feel very elegant. Please post your answer if you have a better solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `uniq` method, just append it at the end

```
Store.joins(:open_hours).order("#{current_time} > open_time AND #{current_time} < close_time desc").uniq
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick response! I tried appending the `uniq` method to the end and I also had to add the order by expression to the select statement, so my query becomes: `Store.select("stores.*, #{current_time} > open_time AND #{current_time} < close_time as open").joins(:open_hours).order("#{current_time} > open_time AND #{current_time} < close_time desc").uniq`. Unfortunately there are still a few duplicates, but not as many as before

Comment: What happens if you put the `uniq` after the `joins(:open_hours)`?  E.g., `Store.joins(:open_hours).uniq.order("#{current_time} > open_time AND #{current_time} < close_time desc")`

Comment: @user1002119, thanks for the suggestion. It actually gives me the same result as appending `uniq` to the end.